# Is there a way to import an Excel file into MS SQL on Flex?

Tags: sql, excel, apache-flex, actionscript, coldfusion

My application needs a component that allows the users to upload an Excel file (.xls) and import its columns into a MS SQL table, using a web-based Flex application.

Is it possible to make it on Flex?

If so, any examples?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: What have you tried? Post some sample code or specific questions or error messages.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to with coldfusion.  or does it.  I know of tools to consume excel files in coldfusion (which brought me to the question), my question is: is any part of your application coldfusion facing? If you are only concerned about flex...then remove that coldfusion tag...

Comment: @FrankTudor, I use ColdFusion in order to retrive and send data from and to my DB, and I read something about using CF to do what I want, so, currently I'm researching on it.

Comment: No, that is something you would do on the middle tier.  And what is your main goal, importing columns seems like it could be done in a better way, such as using a DDL.

Comment: @mx1810 ok I whipped up an answer for you. Its Excel and Coldfusion (the example is with CSV), but I have included what you need to add/look for. Take a look-see.

Answer (score 1):

For consuming Excel files I use Ben Nadel's POI wrapper which can be found here.

https://github.com/bennadel/POIUtility.cfc

To use it, I have a front uplaod page that I schedule to look int o an FTP directory to see if there is a file to consume.  To illustrate this I am simplifying the process and grabbing a local file...

First I initialize the functions using createObject() for the POIUtility.cfc so I can access the methods. Something like this:

```
<cfset importUploads = createObject("component", "cfcs.POIUtility").init()>
```

I have CSV files so I am using the CSV part of the tool like this:

```
<cfset csvToArrayTemp = importUploads.csvtoarray()>
```

but you'll be using the `importUploads.ReadExcel()` instead.

I need to roll this stuff into tables so I do this:

```
<cfoutput>
<cfloop from="2" to="#ArrayLen(csvToArrayTemp)#" index="i">
    <cftry>

    <cfquery datasource="mhsdoctors">                
    INSERT INTO [mhsdoctors].[c3design].[profilesaaa]
               ([ID]
               ,[First]
               ,[Middle]
               ,[Last]
               ,[Title]
               ,[Gender]
               ,[Photo]
               ,[School]
               ,[Address])
         VALUES
               ('#csvToArrayTemp[i][13]#'
               ,'#csvToArrayTemp[i][2]#'
               ,'#csvToArrayTemp[i][3]#'
               ,'#csvToArrayTemp[i][1]#'
               ,'#csvToArrayTemp[i][4]#'
               ,'#csvToArrayTemp[i][12]#''
               <cfif csvToArrayTemp[i][13] eq '11111111'>
               ,'frank-tudor-2014.jpg'
               <cfelseif csvToArrayTemp[i][13] eq '11111112'>
               ,'frank.png'
               <cfelse>
               ,'#replacenocase(csvToArrayTemp[i][15],'\\picDir\people\pictures\','','all')#'
               </cfif>
               ,'#csvToArrayTemp[i][8]#'
               ,'#csvToArrayTemp[i][6]#')                
    </cfquery>                           
    <cfcatch>
    <cfmail from="frank@c3design.com" to="frank@emailEmergency.com" subject="The import failed">Check the file for crap data. #csvToArrayTemp[i][13]#</cfmail>
    </cfcatch>
    </cftry>
</cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

Notice that I am matching my table fields up to the particular column in the csv file. I have to code for exceptions all over and I have placed an example of this above with the picture. You'll most likely need to do this too.

To do a screen scan of data (so you can see the structures and spot check problems), increase your time out then add a cfdump to your loop interation...(note this will suck massive resource and do a cfsetting increase on your timeout I do 99999 or whatever (see below):

(put this at the top)

```
<cfsetting requesttimeout="999999999">
```

(after you grab your file)

```
<cfdump var="#csvToArrayTemp#" abort>
```

Now on to the POI CFC thingy.

I set my file variable there like this.

```
<!--- Define the local scope. --->
<cfset var local = {} />
    <cfif FileExists('C:\someplace\important\1001.txt.csv')>
    <cfset arguments.csv = fileRead( 'C:\someplace\important\1001.txt.csv' ) />
    <cfelse>
    <cfmail from="frank@ultraEmergency.com" to="frank@ultraEmergency.com" subject="The import failed">The file wasn't there...panic!</cfmail><cfabort>
    </cfif>
<cfif arguments.trim>
```

This next block of code holds my replace snippets with some real word examples because I usually run into junk user import that stops my import from working right.

```
<!--- Remove trailing line breaks and carriage returns. --->
<cfset arguments.csv = reReplace(
    arguments.csv,
    "[\r\n]+$",
    "",
    "all"
    ) />
<cfset arguments.csv = replaceNoCase(
    arguments.csv,
    "Hap""""",
    "",
    "1"
    ) />     
<cfset arguments.csv = reReplace(
    arguments.csv,
    ", Suite",
    " Suite",
    "all"
    ) />  
<cfset arguments.csv = reReplace(
    arguments.csv,                
    '14SW "U" St',
    '14SW U St',
    'one'
    ) />
```

I let the POI utility work its dark magic. Provided everything goes swimmingly, I have a table filled with the data I need and then I move on to some additional housekeeping steps like archiving the consumed file in a safe place just in case I need it for something like a spot data check or a manual import.

All this is setup with a nice scheduled task in the Coldfusion administration to trigger  twice a month during low traffic periods.

I hope this helps or at least gets you started.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with xlsx files because they are just zip archives with xml files inside. 
You can find specification on Microsoft website. But be aware that it contains more than 5000 pages.